# Overstayed 18 years in the US

Tags: visas, usa, overstaying

I overstayed for 18  years in the US. I had an H1B that expired in 2004 that abled me to get an SSN. The expiration of my H1B wasn't my fault but because of technical reasons. I continued working for different employers and never missed paying and filing for my taxes. I have no criminal record. I'm not in the US any longer. Is it possible or just a suicide for me to apply for a new US visa under my maiden name.  If possible, any advice? Thank you

Comment: Your H1-B expired in 2004?  That was 15 years ago.  How did you manage to overstay for 18 years in a 15-year period?

Comment: Expiry of your H1B may not have been your fault, but staying 15 years out of status most certainly is. You can apply for a visa but it's unlikely you'll ever get one.

Comment: Why use your maiden name? I believe the visa application asks about other names.

Comment: @NateEldredge she could have been out of status earlier than the visa expiration date.

Comment: Have I misunderstood or is the idea of applying under your maiden name an attempt to hide your previous overstay? Thereby adding deception to your immigration history? Your chances of getting a visa seem remote but perhaps consulting an Immigration lawyer would be a good idea

Comment: If you have legally resumed your maiden name, then of course it is correct to apply under that name. The application asks about former names *because* of the possibility that someone could hide something this way. You *must* disclose your name change.

Answer (score 2):

It's just suicide. Forget about visiting the USA any time soon.

Immigration is about you as a person, not about the name or passport you use. Application forms ask about former names and former passports. Lying on an application form to try to get around a ban is the sort of thing that gets you banned for life.

Comment: Suicide is a tragedy that afflicts many families. I think it is inappropriate to suggest that a visa refusal could be somehow comparable.

Comment: @RichardBeasley I was just using the language from the question: if you object to it, take it up with the asker.